# text unarangeable in position fixed

Tags: css, fixed

hello guys I am a beginner of CSS
I was trying to make a webpage and I was making header
but when I used the `position: fixed;` command my header shrink and goes to the right side of the page
and the text that was arranged in a row like this *text text text*
some text goes in the below
row *text text text*
and I cant fix it plz help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi! please add width 100% and z-index to the fixed position div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly welcome to web development! When posting here it can be helpful to include a snippet of the code you're having trouble with so people can be more specific with their answers.

since I don't know what your header code looks like this will be a bit more general, but i'll include some possible fixes for your issue and an example header you can use for ideas.

```css
.header-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  ...restOfStyles
}
```

this should fix your issues with the fixed header, but I also wanted to recommend looking into `position: sticky;` by design fixed doesn't interact with the rest of your layout, this means for a header you would need to set a margin or padding on the top of your page content to stop it covering content before scrolling the page.

`position: sticky;` will keep your other page elements positioned around it, but with a `top`  value defined will pin itself to the top of the window as the user scrolls past it - meaning you don't have to add padding to account for the height of the header.

it's more or less the same code, just switching out the positioning property;

```css
.header-container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  ...restOfStyles
}
```

happy coding!

edit: Just wanted to include some resources to help you on your journey;

- [Flexbox Zombies - an interactive game for learning flex](https://mastery.games/post/flexboxzombies2/)
- [Grid Critters - an interactive game for learning grid](https://mastery.games/gridcritters/)
- [MDN Web Docs - documentation for all things web development, most things have extensive examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)